# for_each as a lambda function

Tags: c++, lambda

I tried to write for_each as a lambda function, where every value of a `std::array` should be copied to another one. My current code looks like this:

```
std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine eng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(MIN, MAX);

    std::array<int, 20> random_numbers;

    std::cout << "Original: " << std::endl;

    

    for (int i = 0; i != random_numbers.size(); i++) {
        random_numbers[i] = distr(eng);
        std::cout << random_numbers[i] << std::endl;
    }


    auto copy_numbers = std::for_each(random_numbers.begin(), random_numbers.end(), [n = 20](const std::array<int, 20> rn) {
        return rn.at(n);
    });
```

However, there is something wrong with my lambda function. `:: operator () (const std :: array <_Ty, 20>) const": Conversion of argument 1 from "_Ty" to "const std :: array <int, 20> "not possible`. Does anybody know what is wrong with the function?

Comment: Sounds like you just want `auto copy_numbers = random_numbers;` [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) is for iterating over every element and doing something with it.

Comment: `std::for_each` (1) expects a callable object that accepts a single element as a parameter, as opposed to the entire container, and (2) returns that callable object. So whatever you are trying to do with it is most likely better done with something else.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::array<int, 20> random_numbers;
```

This is a container of `int`s. Iterating through this container will iterate over `int` values.

`std::for_each` is just iterating over a sequence that's defined by a beginning and an ending iterator, and then invokes the callable object with a reference to each value in the sequence. That's ***all*** that it does, and not a single thing in addition to that.

```
[n = 20](const std::array<int, 20> rn) {
```

The parameter to this callable object is a `std::array`. However, as I explained above, `std::for_each` will pass to this callable object a reference to each value in the sequence. Which is an `int`. You cannot convert an `int` to a `std::array<int, 20>`, this is not a valid conversion.

```
return rn.at(n);
```

There are a number of problems here, but the main one is that `std::for_each` does absolutely nothing, whatsoever, with whatever the callable object returns. The return value is completely ignored. All that `std::for_each` does is iterate over the sequence defined by its first two parameters, and invoke the third parameter with a reference to each value in the sequence. Its job is done, at that point.

```
auto copy_numbers = std::for_each(
```

`std::for_each` returns a copy of its third parameter. What you will get here is a copy of the anonymous lambda, and not anything related to the original sequence. You expect to get here a copy of the original container, but that's not what `std::for_each` returns.

You appear to be under the impression that `std::for_each` invokes the callable object for each value in the sequence and then uses the return value from the callable object to construct a new container. However that's not what `std::for_each` does. This is remotely similar to what `std::transform` does, but it does that in a fundamentally different way, and not like this.

Answer (score 0):

1.You cannot initialize `n` while capturing, you have to declare `n` elsewhere and capture it.

2.`std::for_each` could be implemented as follows:

```
template<class InputIt, class UnaryFunction>
constexpr UnaryFunction for_each(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        f(*first);
    }
    return f; // implicit move since C++11
}
```

as you can see, the return type of lambda is not an array, but the UnaryFunction pointer f, so you cannot just copy whatever `std::for_each` return in a variable as an array.

What you intended to do can be done with the help of the following code

```
int n=0;
std::array<int, 20> copy_numbers;
std::for_each(random_numbers.begin(), random_numbers.end(), [&n, &copy_numbers](int a){
    copy_numbers[n++] = a;
});
```

Btw, here is some additional reading.

https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/lambda-captures/

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each